# What are the Fedora 19 root credentials?

Tags: linux, authentication, root, fedora, redhat

I've downloaded the fedora 19 disk image from [this](http://fedoraproject.org/en/download-cloud-splash?file=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/19/Images/x86_64/Fedora-x86_64-19-20130627-sda.qcow2) source. I'm installing it on a RHEL6.4 machine in the cloud. The image installs successfully, but it doesn't give any login credentials.

I was just curious as to what the defaults were because I can't seem to find any documentation on them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually be the root user, you can become the root of your user account, which is probably fine.
Try `$sudo -s` or `$sudo -i`